# Abort() when starting up a few threads with std::vector<std::future<int>> and std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, c++11, future

I am using 4 threads to create a few objects using a `thread_local` memory pool.

I am using `std::vector<std::future<int>>` and `std::async(std::launch::async, function);` to dispatch the threads and `std::for_each` with `t.get` to get their value back. Here's the code:

```
struct GameObject
{
    int x_, y_, z_;
    int m_cost;

    GameObject() = default;
    GameObject(int x, int y, int z, int cost)
        : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z), m_cost(cost)
    {}
};

struct Elf : GameObject
{
    Elf() = default;
    Elf(int x, int y, int z, int cost)
        : GameObject(x, y, z, cost)
    {
        std::cout << "Elf created" << '\n';
    }

    ~Elf() noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "Elf destroyed" << '\n';
    }
    std::string m_cry = "\nA hymn for Gandalf\n";
};

struct Dwarf : GameObject
{
    Dwarf() = default;
    Dwarf(int x, int y, int z, int cost)
        : GameObject(x, y, z, cost)
    {
        std::cout << "dwarf created" << '\n';
    }

    ~Dwarf() noexcept
    {
        std::cout << "dwarf destroyed" << '\n';
    }
    std::string m_cry = "\nFind more cheer in a graveyard\n";
};


int elvenFunc()
{
    thread_local ObjectPool<Elf> elvenPool{ 229 };
    for (int i = 0; i < elvenPool.getSize(); ++i)
    {
        Elf* elf = elvenPool.construct(i, i + 1, i + 2, 100);
        std::cout << elf->m_cry << '\n';
        elvenPool.destroy(elf);
    }

    thread_local std::promise<int> pr;
    pr.set_value(rand());

    return 1024;
}

int dwarvenFunc()
{
    thread_local ObjectPool<Dwarf> dwarvenPool{ 256 };
    for (int i = 0; i < dwarvenPool.getSize(); ++i)
    {
        Dwarf* dwarf = dwarvenPool.construct(i - 1, i - 2, i - 3, 100);
        std::cout << dwarf->m_cry << '\n';
        dwarvenPool.destroy(dwarf);
    }

    thread_local std::promise<int> pr;
    pr.set_value(rand());

    return 2048;
}


int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    srand(time(0));

    std::vector<std::future<int>> vec{ 4 };
    vec.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, elvenFunc));
    vec.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, elvenFunc));
    vec.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, dwarvenFunc));
    vec.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, dwarvenFunc));

    int term = 0;
    try
    {
        std::for_each(std::execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&term](std::future<int>& t)
        {
            auto ret = t.get();
            std::cout << "thread brought me " << ret << '\n';
            term += ret;
        });
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Final word = " << term << '\n';
}
```

(the `construct` and `destroy` call `allocate` and `deallocate` internally.) I get a lot of expected output from the terminal, but somewhere along the lines `abort` gets called and the program doesn't complete normally. I can't find out why. I believe that the `t.get()` call of a thread that's been started with std::async automatically calls `.join` too right?

Using C++17 and Visual Studio 2017. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour. You call `get` on non-valid future. Your vector of futures has first 4 items as empty `future`. `get` can be called only if `future::valid` returns true.

What do you think this line

```
std::vector<std::future<int>> vec{ 4 };
```

does ?

> Default constructor. Constructs a std::future with no shared state.
>   After construction, valid() == false.

And [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/get) you can read what happens when `future::get` is called:

> The behavior is undefined if valid() is false before the call to this
>   function.